# Corrigir código de carregamento de posts

Tags: javascript, blogger

Estou personalizando esse template e o "load more posts" das "latest post" entra em looping infinito, não carregando as postagens.

Não tenho certeza se o código está carregando o javascript corretamente.
O template que estou usando é este: http://gooyaabitemplates.com/livepreview/punjab-press-responsive-blogger-template/

Esse é o script, tem algo errado com ele pra não carregar?

```
<script class='jshilang' type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
            searchxx({summaryLength:100,scrthumbSize:50});   
            jQuery('.sidebar h2, .footer h2').wrapInner('<span/>');
            callregex(jQuery);
        //]]>
    </script>

    <b:if cond='data:blog.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'>    
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;static_page&quot;'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;item&quot;'>
        <script class='jshilang' type='text/javascript'>
            //<![CDATA[
viewMode({
  viewmodedefault:'list',
  cookielist:'list1',
  cookiegrid:'grid1'
});
loadMorePost({
  viewmodedefault:'list',
  cookielist:'list1',
  cookiegrid:'grid1'
});
            //]]>
        </script>
```

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Uma boa prática para iniciarmos uma discussão saudável é ler o [Guia de Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Comece seguindo estas recomendações, principalmente sabendo quais os tipos de perguntas deve fazer, como criar um exemplo mínimo que seja completo e verificável e até mesmo o que fazer quando alguém te responder.

Comment: Obrigada! Coloquei o script que encontrei no template pra saber se ele está correto.